# jquery infinitescroll how to append data

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I want to write a function to do a simple thing. I have 10 pages of data and each page has 20 records. When user goes to the bottom of page one and clicks **Load More**, I want to load the data of page two and **append** these data to displayed data of page one.

I found a jquery plugin called infinitescroll. It works fine for me except that I cannot append the newer data.

My html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log({
                {
                    $p - > getCurrentPage()
                }
            });
            var $container = $('#masonny-div');
            $container.infinitescroll({
                loading: {
                    msg: null,
                    msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
                    speed: 'fast',
                },
                navSelector: "#next",
                nextSelector: "#next a",
                itemSelector: "#masonny-div",
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='masonny-div'>
        @foreach ($p as $x)
        <div class="item">{{$x -> name}}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="next">
        <a href="{{$p->getUrl($p->getCurrentPage() + 1)}}">Next</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is link to the next page: `$p->getUrl($p->getCurrentPage() + 1`

Every time when I click it, I get the **next** page's data, but how so I append that to the last page?

I tried to invoke the callback function but that is not working. There is no message in the console.

```
var $container = $('#masonny-div');
$container.infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        msg: null,
        msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
        speed: 'fast',
    },
    navSelector: "#next",  
    nextSelector: "#next a",  
    itemSelector: "#masonny-div",             
}, function(data){
    console.log('I am here!');
    console.log(data);
});
```

Any information is welcome, thanks.

Comment: u r using some templating . which one it is...

Comment: @vishalsharma  laravel4

Comment: Have you tried to use classes instead of Ids?

Comment: @Bellash nope, just copy and make a little modify from the demo

Comment: @vishalsharma it's blade probably

Answer (score 2):

are you using the latest version?

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

i think there is a new option:

```
appendCallback: true
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the latest version try these :

1. Set `appendCallback:true` , already suggested by @Greg
2. Pass a function to finish option : `finish:funciton(content){//do somethting}`.

   From the [doc](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/wiki/Callback) :

   > The finished function is called after each AJAX call that loads new content, after the loading message is displayed. If the option is not overridden, or a falsy value is passed it, the default action will be to fade-out the loading message.

   And line#376 of [infinitescroll.js](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js) source code indicates that it passed the output which it's retrieved to append in the DOM.

   ```
       opts.loading.finished.call($(opts.contentSelector)[0],opts);
   ```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a different "itemSelector". something like that:

```
   $container.infinitescroll({
        loading: {
            msg: null,
            msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
            speed: 'fast',
        },
        navSelector: "#next",
        nextSelector: "#next a",  
        itemSelector: "#masonny-div div.item",             
    });
```

Comment: @diligent did you tried my answer? It should work according to doc

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob thanks man, its not working, even I use static html files, its not working. I read its source code, did not find the reason. Still, thanks man.

Comment: can you give the result of the use of the option: `errorCallback: function(){console.log('test');}` Where did you find that the options contains `loading:{...}` the doc talk about loadingText and loadingImg?

Comment: @Pierre thanks. I've solved the problem, later, I'll posts my solution :)